# SMTP mail : How to bind data table values to a html template C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api, smtp

I am new to c# and WEB Api ,I want to send mail after each purchase of a product .
Mail will have all the details related to the purchased product.

Here I have the code which is working fine while sending string data as a mail .

I don't know how to add data table values to the HTML template and send it as a mail.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h4 style="color:   #00CED1">Purchase Details<hr></h4>

    <table style="width:100%;border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <th>Item(s)<hr></th>
            <th>Details<hr></th>
            <th>Amount(Tax.Inc)<hr></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff" /></td>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;margin-left:15px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Product Name :</td>
                        <td align="left" style="color:#32CD32;font-weight:bold;">Red chilly powder</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Product UOM :</td>
                        <td align="left" style="color:#696969;font-weight:bold;">PKT 500</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Quantity :</td>
                        <td align="left" style="color:#778899;font-weight:bold;">5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Unit Price :</td>
                        <td align="left" style="color:#483D8B;font-weight:bold;">30 $
                        <td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#1E90FF">150 $</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <hr>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Total Amount :
            <td align="right" style="color:#0000CD;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">150 $</td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>

</body>
</html>
```

API

```
 foreach (DataRow Row in Tables[0].Rows)
    {
     //Here I want to iterate the table rows.
    }
sendMail(string mMailBody);
```

I have searched in SO but I can find only sending string as a SMTP mail.can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bunch of different templates I'd suggest choosing advanced solution like [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/) or [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), but if it's the only case you need to cover, you could do something simple as separating your HTML template in two parts - mail body and table row, build your table row collection and inject it into the mail body.

Mail Body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h4 style="color:   #00CED1">Purchase Details<hr></h4>

    <table style="width:100%;border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <th>Item(s)<hr></th>
            <th>Details<hr></th>
            <th>Amount(Tax.Inc)<hr></th>
        </tr>

        {0}

    </table>
    <hr>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" style="font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">Total Amount :
            <td align="right" style="color:#0000CD;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;">{1}</td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Table Row

```
<tr>
    <td align="center"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff" /></td>
    <td>
        <table style="width:100%;margin-left:15px">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Product Name :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#32CD32;font-weight:bold;">{0}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Product UOM :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#696969;font-weight:bold;">{1}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Quantity :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#778899;font-weight:bold;">{2}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Unit Price :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#483D8B;font-weight:bold;">{3}<td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#1E90FF">{4}</td>
</tr>
```

Then the code

```
// Retrieve the templates and store them into mailBodyTemplate and tableRowTemplate
// For example,
var mailBodyTemplate = File.ReadAllText("mailBody.html");
var tableRowTemplate = File.ReadAllText("tableRow.html");

var tableRows = new StringBuilder();
var totalPrice = 0;
foreach (DataRow Row in Tables[0].Rows)
{
    totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(Row["Price"]);
    tableRows.AppendFormat(tableRowTemplate, Row["Name"], Row["UOM"], Row["Quantity"], Row["UnitPrice"], Row["Price"]);
}
var mailBody = string.Format(mailBodyTemplate, tableRows.ToString(), totalPrice);
// Send your mail body
```

Comment: How Can I include tableRowTemplate and tableBodyTemplate inside the 3rd part @Imantas Sankalas

Comment: The simplest yet ugliest way is just to hardcode them as strings. However, I suggest moving them to files and do the [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_) `var mailBodyTemplate = File.ReadAllText("path/to/mailBody.html");`

Comment: I can display the images by using the above html template. Can you help me in this .@Imantas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002475/smtp-mail-not-displaying-the-image?noredirect=1#comment94841679_54002475

Comment: I am new to this ,In my case How can I implement this concept @Imantas