# SMTP mail not displaying the image

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I am new to web api ,Here I am sending mail using SMTP service .

In this I need to send images I mean I need to display the image along with the mail contents.

But in my case contents are properly displaying but the image is not .

The data of image URL is  : `http://192.168.168.62:8087/Images/Product/My_Cart/axe_brand_1.jpg`

When I inspect the image in the mail box it shows as follows:

```
 <img data-imagetype="External" src="/actions/ei?u=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.168.62%3A8087%2FImages%2FProduct%2FMy_Cart%2Faxe_brand_1.jpg&amp;d=2019-01-02T05%3A52%3A02.212Z" originalsrc="http://192.168.168.62:8087/Images/Product/My_Cart/axe_brand_1.jpg" data-connectorsauthtoken="1" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" data-imageproxyid="">
```

I have tried many ways to solve this I can't .Can anyone help me to solve this .

**Update :**

c#:

```
 foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(Row["ITEM_IMAGE"].ToString());
                        res.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        string htmlBody = @"<img src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"'/>";

                        tableRows.AppendFormat(mailBodyTemplate, htmlBody, Row["ITEM_NAME"], Row["ITEM_UOM"], Row["QUANTITY"], Row["ITEM_PRICE_WITH_GST"], Row["TOTAL_AMOUNT_WITH_GST"]);
                    }
   var mailBody = string.Format(PurchaseSummary, tableRows.ToString(), totalPrice);
```

Template :

```
<tr>
    <td align="center"><img src="{0}" /></td>
    <td>
        <table style="width:100%;margin-left:15px">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width:50%">Product Name :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#32CD32;font-weight:bold;width:50%">{1}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width:50%">Product UOM :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#696969;font-weight:bold;width:50%">{2}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width:50%">Quantity :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#778899;font-weight:bold;width:50%">{3}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width:50%">Unit Price :</td>
                <td align="left" style="color:#483D8B;font-weight:bold;width:50%">{4}
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#1E90FF">{5}</td>

</tr>
```

still it's not displaying the image .

While inspecting the image I got as follows..

```
<img data-imagetype="External" src="/actions/ei?u=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.168.62%3A8087%2FImages%2FProduct%2FMy_Cart%2Faxe_brand_1.jpg&amp;d=2019-01-02T09%3A41%3A12.195Z" originalsrc="http://192.168.168.62:8087/Images/Product/My_Cart/axe_brand_1.jpg" data-connectorsauthtoken="1" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" data-imageproxyid="">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with webapi, neither smtp. https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

Comment: please see the inspect data after applying the cid. @ZorgoZ

Comment: @Zhu you can't use URL for CID, you need to add image as an attachment and then insert the CID of the attached file.

Comment: please take a look at my updated code @Imantas still it's not displaying the image

Comment: @Zhu I think the problem is that you're attaching URL of the image, not the binary image itself. If you have it locally, just do something like `File.ReadAllBytes` or if it's remote, use `WebClient.DownloadFile`.

Comment: I am storing the images in the Images folder of API and passing the Image url to the mail body .So what Should I need to do to display the image in this case @Imantas

Comment: @Zhu have you read the link from my comment? There you can see that there are at least three ways to add image to a html formatted email. But these are distinct approaches, you can't combine them. But currently, you are traying to. What you get from the client is something it managed to figure out from your attempt. Forget trying to fix the result you see in the client, try first to produce valid content.